# Django Database Router allow_migrate method

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm trying to setup a database router to route my models to postgresql and redshift. I have an app within my project with multiple models. The database router should route the 1 model to redshift and all others to postgresql, however, I get the below errors when I run migrations.

**"python manage.py migrate --database redshift"**

**SyntaxError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "django_migrations"**

**ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "django_migrations"**

**MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "django_migrations"
)**

===============================================================

I'm confused by this as I do not have a django_migrations table in redshfit yet, which leads me to believe that my router is not working correctly and my logic for allow_migrate method is not correct. I'm new to django and this has me at my wits end. If anyone can provide any clarifying information or point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

NOTE: I've looked at the django documentation and built my router based off the examples they provided.

Thanks!

Below is my router, model Meta class example and database config.

**routers.py**

```
class DbRouter:
    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            if model._meta.model_name == 'RedshiftModel':
                return 'redshift'
            else:
                return 'default'
        return None
    
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            if model._meta.model_name == 'RedshiftModel':
                return 'redshift'
            else:
                return 'default'
        return None
    
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'myapp' or obj2.app_label == 'myapp':
            return True
        return None
        
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'myapp':
            if model_name == 'RedshiftModel':
                return db == 'redshift'
            else:
                return db == 'default'
        return None
```

**models.py**

```
class RedshiftModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"int". "redshift_table"'
        app_label = 'myapp'
```

And finally, my database config

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('PORT'),
    },
    'redshift': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_redshift_backend',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('RDATABASE'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('RUSER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('RPASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('RHOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('RPORT'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=int'
        }
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'myproject.settings.routers.DbRouter'
]
```